# Passing *args through a tkinter bind function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a lot of buttons and I use images in them so I created a class to make it readable but I have a problem because I have sometimes a multiple arguments functions (to use it in the bind section below).

This is my code:

```
class myButton():

  def __init__(self, master, relx: float, rely: float, relwidth: float, relheight: float, color, image, function, *args):
    self.master = master
    self.relx = relx
    self.rely = rely
    self.relwidth = relwidth
    self.relheight = relheight
    self.color = color
    self.image = image
    self.function = function

    self.myButton = Button(master, bg=self.color, image=self.image, activebackground=self.color, bd=0)
    self.myButton.place(relx=self.relx, rely=self.rely, relheight=self.relheight, relwidth=self.relwidth)
    # The problem is in the following line
    self.myButton.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, *args: self.function(event, *args))

  def place_forget(self):
    self.myButton.place_forget()

  def show(self):
    self.myButton.place(relx=self.relx, rely=self.rely, relheight=self.relheight, relwidth=self.relwidth)
```

Do you have any suggestions?

When I pass argument in the place of `*args` I get an error that arguments are missing

Exemples of Entries

First with error

```
buttonname1 = myButton(master1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, color_main_content, ButtonValidate,
                                       function, argument1, argument1)
```

function1 is multivariable function

ButtonValidate is an image

argument1 and argument2 (maybe more arguments for other functions)

definition of the function

```
def function(event, argument1, argument2):
    pass # main function
```

Example without multiple arguments

```
buttonname2 = myButton(master2, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, color_main_content, ButtonNext,
                                       function1)
```

definition of function 2

```
def function2(event):
   pass
```

I want a class that works for both situations

Error Message:

TypeError: function() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'argument1' and 'argument2'

Comment: What is the problem, what is the function. And what `args` are you passing in.

Comment: Each Button Created in a tkinter has a function and sometimes these functions have multiple arguments (I use the function in the bind method of Button)

Comment: So if the function has multiple arguments i pass them in when I create an object of the class myButton

Comment: and if i run the code with no *args the code works (function with just event argument) but if the function has more than one argument the button won't work correctly

Comment: Paste the error code, and also how you instantiate this widget.

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Try: `def function(event, *args):` ?